# running subquery only on results of parent query

Tags: mysql, optimization, sum, subquery, match

I am running a search query for a site that collects `element` that match the query. However, there may or may not be one or more `items` that are linked to the `element`. So, I have a subquery that counts the matches of all of the `items` linked to an `element`.

This query does work. But incredibly slowly. It takes me around 50 seconds at the moment. If I ditch the subquery it is much, much faster.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, 
    MATCH (e.heading) AGAINST ('+(room)') AS h_score, 
    MATCH (e.text) AGAINST ('+(room)') AS t_score, 
    ( 
        SELECT SUM( MATCH (item.heading, item.text) AGAINST ('+(room)') ) AS itemscore 
             FROM item LEFT JOIN _element_item ON item.id = _element_item.item_id 
             WHERE _element_item.item_id = e.id 
             AND MATCH (item.heading, item.text) AGAINST ('+(room)')
    ) AS i_score 

    FROM element AS e 
    LEFT JOIN _element_brand ON e.id = _element_brand.element_id 
    LEFT JOIN _element_language ON e.id = _element_language.element_id 
    LEFT JOIN _element_region ON e.id = _element_region.element_id 
    LEFT JOIN _element_type ON e.id = _element_type.element_id 
    LEFT JOIN _element_group ON e.id = _element_group.element_id     

    WHERE _element_brand.brand_id = 1 
    AND _element_language.language_iso = 'en' 
    AND _element_region.region_id = 1 
    AND _element_type.type_id = 1 
    AND _element_group.group_id = 1 
    AND e.replacement_id IS NULL 
    AND e.status = 1 
    AND MATCH (e.heading, e.text) AGAINST ('+(room)') 
    ORDER BY t_score + h_score DESC LIMIT 100
```

Is there a way to get this to run faster?

I'm guessing it is running the full subquery for every `element` before matching the `element`? Could I get it to only run the subquery on matches in the parent query? If so, how?

Comment: You have LEFT JOINs, but then follow your WHERE clause to have specific criteria against those tables, thus resulting in an INNER JOIN.  Was that your intent, or did you really mean for them to be LEFT JOINs.  If so, move your AND criteria to the corresponding LEFT JOIN.

Comment: IF I'm honest I think they ended up as LEFT JOINs because that's what worked. But I'm only looking for the specific elements that match the criteria in the linking tables (starting with an underscore). I'm not interested in values in the joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to clarify the left-join for your sample scenarios.

```
select e.heading
   FROM element AS e
           LEFT JOIN _element_brand 
              ON e.id = _element_brand.element_id 
   WHERE 
          e.SomeColumn = 'test'
      AND _element_brand.brand_id = 1
```

is the same thing as

```
select e.heading
   FROM element AS e
           JOIN _element_brand 
              ON e.id = _element_brand.element_id 
   WHERE 
          e.SomeColumn = 'test'
      AND _element_brand.brand_id = 1
```

because the WHERE clause is FORCING to only return records that DO have a matching _element_brand record AND that record's brand_id = 1.  So this will return only records where the "e.SomeColumn = 'test'"  AND the brand_id = 1.

Now, look at a true left-join

```
select e.heading
   FROM element AS e
           LEFT JOIN _element_brand 
              ON e.id = _element_brand.element_id 
             AND _element_brand.brand_id = 1 
   WHERE 
      e.SomeColumn = 'test'
```

This will return all records from element that have "e.SomeColumn = 'test'"  REGARDLESS of having an entry in the _element_Brand table and the _element_brand.brand_id = 1.

So, if you had 100 elements with SomeColumn = 'test', and of those, 50 records had valid records in the _element_brand table for the corresponding ID.  Of those 50, only 20 specificcally had a brand_id = 1...

The first two sample queries (left-join with WHERE, and the join) would ONLY return the 20 records that specifically had the 20 records.

The LAST query would still return the 100 records that just qualified based on 'test'.

Hope this clarifies if based on your data scenario... sometimes seeing in a book or document might not actually clarify someone trying to grasp it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      STRAIGHT_JOIN
      e.id, 
      MATCH (e.heading) AGAINST ('+(room)') AS h_score, 
      MATCH (e.text) AGAINST ('+(room)') AS t_score, 
      ( SELECT SUM( MATCH (item.heading, item.text) AGAINST ('+(room)') ) 
           FROM _element_item
              JOIN item 
                 ON _element_item.item_id = item.id  
                AND MATCH (item.heading, item.text) AGAINST ('+(room)')
           WHERE 
              e.id = _element_item.item_id ) AS i_score 
   FROM 
      element AS e 
         JOIN _element_brand 
            ON e.id = _element_brand.element_id 
            AND _element_brand.brand_id = 1 

         JOIN _element_language 
            ON e.id = _element_language.element_id 
            AND _element_language.language_iso = 'en' 

         JOIN _element_region 
            ON e.id = _element_region.element_id 
           AND _element_region.region_id = 1 

         JOIN _element_type 
           ON e.id = _element_type.element_id 
          AND _element_type.type_id = 1 

         JOIN _element_group ON e.id = _element_group.element_id     
          AND _element_group.group_id = 1 
   WHERE 
          e.status = 1 
      and e.replacement_id IS NULL 
      AND MATCH (e.heading, e.text) AGAINST ('+(room)') 
   ORDER BY 
      t_score + h_score DESC 
   LIMIT 100
```

I've restructured to joins.  In addition, slightly altered your field select sum() for i_score that appears to be killing your query.  I also added keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" at the top to tell the query run in the order presented.

My only review question on the field select... You are joining

e.id to _element_item.item_id, then from _element_item.item_id to item.id....

So, that said, it MIGHT be simplified that

e.id = item.id and you can completely remove the _element_item table if they truly are the same, but it appears to be a bridge table that for a given element could have many items.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was what I was achieving with the 'WHERE _element_item.item_id = e.id'. But I've been staring at the code so long my brain is mush! Does that not do what I want? If not, what am I not understanding?

Comment: @ironinthesoul, revised answer for left-join clarification.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp, very well explained. I've changed my joins to inner joins now. I should really know this but it sometimes gets missed. The change in joins has shaved a small amount off my query but not a massive amount. My page is generated in 52 seconds, but if I remove the subquery it drops to 3 seconds. Still looking for a solution to speeding it up. I can't see how to tie it better to only the relevant parent results. But from what I understand, the subquery is run first, so perhaps I can't do anything about that?

Comment: @ironinthesoul, revised answer... maybe can help.

Comment: Thanks once again @DRapp. I guess I've got some way to go to learn SQL to the level I need it! I understand the JOINS a lot better now and I've improved the query with your help. The subquery is much more logical and cleaner. But, unfortunately it is just small gains. I've gone from 52 seconds to around 47 seconds which is still way too long for search results. More...

Comment: I also notices that `i_score` was missing from the ORDER BY clause. Adding that bumped the query up to 104 seconds! I have no idea why that might be. You are correct about _element_item being a bridging table. The element item relationship is many to many so I can't remove it. I've got a horrible feeling I'm going to have to completely rethink my approach. Especially as I have two more subqueries to add to this before it is complete. Thanks very much for your help.